# Steps to expose SSRS reports to the Internet

Tags: reporting-services

So, I'm trying to figure out how best to go about exposing some reports on a SSRS server that's behind the firewall to users on an extranet site, as discussed [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159272%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  My DBAs have set a constraint that I pass Windows credentials to the server to gain access, and that the server remain behind the firewall.  I'm having trouble conceiving of how to do that and still maintain a secure system in a public-facing DMZ.  Here are some of my questions:

1. How can I allow users to authenticate to AD while preventing brute-force account hacking?  In other words, one option is to create an app in the DMZ that accepts a u&p, and attempts to authenticated against AD inside the firewall.  However, I need to prevent repeat trying and failing.
2. Assuming I have an authenticated user, how do I pass that credential to the SSRS server?  What languages or mechanisms exist to accomplish that?  Does this have to be a .NET app or could I manage it through Java?
3. How would I accomplish permitting the user to interact with the SSRS server?  I don't want to loose all the UI functionality of the reports, and I don't want to rewrite it either.  It seems like a hack to write an app that acts as a proxy, but that's all I can think of.  Ideas?

TIA

Comment: Never done it myself so not in a position to answer;  but this TechNet resource may help you https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159272(v=sql.105).aspx